# How to fix: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I am writing a python file server and I want to be able to recv all the data on the buffer. So I made a send function that sends the data along with it's file size but when I send the data there is an attribute error.

I have tried looping around the recv function but couldn't get it to work so I decided to send the size of the data being sent and let the server/client see how much data they have received and if it's less than the amount they are told then they should keep receiving data.

```
def getsizeof(data, tl=0):
    for i in data:
    data = sys.getsizeof(i)
    tl += data
return tl

def send(conn, request):
    length = getsizeof(request)
    length_size = sys.getsizeof(length)
    byte_size = length_size + length
    ###########################################################
    request.insert(0, byte_size) # THIS IS WHERE I GET 'AttributeError: 'bytes' has no attribute 'insert'
    ###########################################################
    conn.sendall(pickle.dumps(request)) # Encoding & sending data
    print(total_length)
```

I am getting an attribute error but when that is fixed i think that it should work and recv all data in the buffer and send correctly with the byte size of the sent data.

Comment: `bytes` objects, like your `request`, are immutable. You could create a new one by doing something like `request = size_as_bytes + request`. Also, `getsizeof` doesn't do what you expect: it returns the size used in memory by an object, and is unrelated to the size it will occupy once you encode it. You will have to decide how you encode your size: how many bytes, byte order....